# Search value in associative array javascript

Tags: javascript, associative-array

## JAVASCRIPT

```
    var error = new Object ({'1a':'1','1b':'1','2a':'1'}); // like this I have defined around 200 values
    if (some condition is true)
          error[id] = 0;  // id is selected dynamically ( '1a' or '1b' or what ever)
```

when all this is done I want to check if any one in Object error still have value '1' or not. I have used the following but it does not seem to work..

```
    for ( i in error)
          if(error[i].value == '1')   -some code-  // this line gives error, not able to read value
```

what should be the correct method...??

Comment: if you set `error[id] = 0` why after you try to read `error[i].value`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply remove `.value`:

```
if(error[i] == '1'){...}
```